# Two jquery widgets are interfering. What might be the cause?

Tags: jquery, slider

*I'm a noob to programming.*
An in-built slider Jquery of my site is interfering with another slider Jquery that I externally added. They work well separately, but when put in together in-built fp-slider doesn't function, while external slider keep working finely. After some searching, I feel like it might be able to get fixed by editing some functions of external slider.

****Here're the functions in my external plugin****

```
<script src="http://,,,/jquery-latest.js"></script>  
<script src="http://,,,,/js/plusone.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">  

jQuery(document).ready(function ()  {
jQuery("#facebook_right").hover(function ()
{jQuery(this).stop(true,false).animate({right: 0}, 500); }, 
function (){
jQuery("#facebook_right").stop(true,false).animate({right: -239},500);});    


jQuery("#twitter_right").hover(function (){
jQuery(this).stop(true,false).animate({right: 0},500);},function (){
jQuery("#twitter_right").stop(true,false).animate({right: -254},500);});

jQuery("#google_plus_right").hover(function(){
jQuery(this).stop(true,false).animate({right: 0},500);},function()
{jQuery("#google_plus_right").stop(true,false).animate({right: -294},500);});   


jQuery("#feedburner_right").hover(function(){
jQuery(this).stop(true,false).animate({right: 0}, 500);},function() 
{jQuery("#feedburner_right").stop(true,false).animate({right: -304 }, 500);});    



jQuery("#youtube_right").hover(function(){
jQuery(this).stop(true,false).animate({right: 0},500);},function(){
jQuery("#youtube_right").stop(true,false).animate({right:-304},500);});});  
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I just fixed the fault by replacing the functions inside the 'jQuery(document).ready(function ()  {' of external slider into the 'jQuery(document).ready(function ()  {' of my site template and referring the .js src file also through the template. So only the divs were left for the widget. It worked.